# Horizontal image scrolling using query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, horizontal-scrolling

I would like to implement a side scrolling image slider like the one found [HERE](http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/demos/horizontal-scrolling/)

I can't get my images to scroll like the one's in the example. This is intended for iPhone screen resolution only.

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/AYj6w/

```
<script type="javascript">$(document).ready(function() {
$('#product-image').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>

<ul id="scroller">
<li><img src="img/products/black-couch.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img/products/brown-couch.jpg"></li>
<li><img src="img/products/red-couch.jpg"></li>
</ul>


#scroller {
float: left;
width: 90%;
height: 77px;
}

#scroller ul {
width: 100%;
}

#scroller li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
width: 122px;
height: 71px;
}

#scroller img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

```
position: relative
```

When you specify width: 100% this is evaluated to the next parent element with `position: relative`. As you have none, this means the whole window, probably not what you want. Add `position: relative` to `#scroller li`.

```
display: table-cell
```

To make a list horizontal, you can define the li elements with display: table-cell

```
white-space: nowrap
```

And to make these elements not wrap, use nowrap

```
overflow: scroll
```

You don't really need the jQuery, you can just specify overflow: scroll on the scroll-wrapper this will make the element scroll automatically

I have addressed all this issues in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AYj6w/3/)